# В django перестали работать все урлы после устарновки allauth, теперь все урлы только из allauth.

Tags: django

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Теперь не работают урлы других приложений, я так понимаю allauth переопределяет все роутеры? Как вернуть прежнее поведение django?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'portal.views.index', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    url(r'^admin/',  include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^блог/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^home/', include('portal.urls')),  #@TODO не работают урлы кроме allauth

)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )
```

Comment: Покажите ваш `urls.py`

Comment: Добавил urls.py

Comment: Передвигать правило allauth в конец списка правил пробовали?